# Is there a usecallback like function in react that can be added to class based component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

The child component keeps rerendering because I am passing a handlderfunction from my class based component(Parent component). How can I prevent rerendering of the child component?

This is my code:

```
render() {
    const eventClickHandler = (activity) => {
        this.props.dispatchGetActivityDetails(activity.id);
    }

    return (
        <ChildComponentHere eventClickHandler={eventClickHandler} /> 
    );
}
```

The Child component is already exported by this:

```
export default memo(WorkspaceActivityList)
```

Comment: Move it to outside of render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your function as a class method, outside the render

```
eventClickHandler = (activity) => {
   this.props.dispatchGetActivityDetails(activity.id)
}

render() {

   return (
      <ChildComponentHere eventClickHandler={this.eventClickHandler} /> 
   );
}
```

The reason your child component keeps on re-rendering is that you are creating a new `eventClickHandler` function on every render of your parent component, which won't be referentially equal to the one created in the previous render.